# PHP highlight query and escape html special characters

Tags: php, html, search, escaping, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to program a search function that hightlights the search query in the result. At the moment I'm using this Code `$hightlight = preg_replace('/'.strtolower($query).'/', '<span class=hightlight>'.strtolower($query).'</span>', strtolower($text));` for highlighting, which works fine.  The text I'm searching in is a string from a database. The problem now is if the text contains some html special characters, and is for example `<test>` and the user searches for `<te` I get the following result: `<span class="hightlight"><te< span="">st&gt;</te<></span>` which is interpretated as `st>`. This makes sense, but I don't want this. I want `<test>` as result with `<te` highlighted. So I need to escape the special characters. I know that there is the function `htmlspecialchars`, but how can I use it in this case? Or another function? I can't escape them before searching, because than I'm also searching in the HTML-Codes. I also can't escape them after searching, because than are the `<span>` Tags in the text and they will also be converted to HTML-Codes. I hope you understand my problem. Has anyone a solution for that?

Comment: What's wrong with just running both the `$query` and the `$text` through `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: @PatrickQ if I for example just search for `t` I get a wrong result because a `>` is as HTML-Code this `&gt;` and `t` as HTML-Code just `t`. so the t inside the HTML-Code of `>` will also be highlighted and the HTML-Code is displayed as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of `htmlspecialchars()` and a regex negative lookahead, I think we're able to solve this.

```
<php
$text = "this is just my really basic <test> of words";
$query = "<te";

$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);

$highlight = preg_replace('/'.strtolower($query).'(?![^\&]*\;)/', '<span class=highlight>'.strtolower($query).'</span>', strtolower($text));

echo $highlight;
?>
```

(small note, I took the liberty of changing `hightlight` to `highlight`)

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8bfd22e9e8007261f5788854af19a601ce2debb5)

The part of this that solves the issue mentioned in your comment is the negative lookahead: `(?![^\&]*\;)`

That basically means anything not between `&` and `;`.

Now, this could obviously run into issues in some edge cases where `&` *and* `;` are *both* part of the actual text.  If you're not doing any sort of text and query limitation/sanitation, I'm not sure that there's anything that will work for *all* possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick, this is definitely better than my solution  and solves my problem. But as you mentioned there are errors when `&` and `;` are both in a query. So the answer is still not perfect. If someone has a better solution (if this is possible) please post it here too.